# how to display JSON data in html div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Here is my JSON string:

```
[[{"name":"Pepe Pinedo"},{"message":"something"},{"datein":"2015-07-01 11:12:34"}],[{"name":"Pepe Pinedo"},{"message":"something"},{"datein":"2015-07-01 11:14:30"}]]
```

here's my js code

```
$.post(url, function( data ) { //fire ajax post request
    alert("Got messages: " + data); //                         
    /*$.each(data, function(index,e){
        content += e.name + ':'+ e.message +'<br>';
        $("#chatbox").append(content);
    });*/    
});
```

I was trying to make the messages look like this:

[image]

Php

```
$messages = $this->person_model->get_msg();
 foreach ($messages as $i => $valor) {
                    $fila['name']       = $valor->names;
                    $message['message'] = $valor->message;
                    $fecha['fecha']     = $valor->datein;
                    $data[] = array($fila, $message,$fecha);

            }
            echo json_encode($data);
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why have one object per property? It would make more sense if you received something like: `[{"name":"Rildo","message":"something","date":"2015-07-01 11:12:34"},{"name":"Rildo","message":"something","date":"2015-07-01 11:14:30"}]`

Comment: i guess something is wrong with my php, im just starting to learn to code so things like that happens to me frequently im going to edit to show my php code

Comment: Please see my answer about the PHP part, and tell me if that solves it.

Comment: ok, thanks for your help im going to try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your data structure would make more sense like this:

```
[
  { "name": "Rildo", "message": "something", "date": "2015-07-01 11:12:34" },
  { "name": "Rildo", "message": "something", "date": "2015-07-01 11:14:30" }
]
```

To do so, you could modify your PHP a bit:

```
$messages = $this->person_model->get_msg();

foreach ($messages as $i => $valor) {
    $data[] = array(
        "name"    => $valor->names,
        "message" => $valor->message,
        "date"    => $valor->datein
    );
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Then, to display it:

```
$.post(url, function( data ) { // Fires an Ajax POST request

    alert("Got messages: " + data); // Alerts a String

    var messages = JSON.parse(data), // Turns the String into an Object you can manipulate
        content = '';

    $.each(messages, function(index,e){
        var time = e.date.substr(-8,5); // Extracts time from date
        content += time + ' ' + e.name + ': ' + e.message + '<br>';
    }); 

    $("#chatbox").append(content);

});
```

#### Demo

```js
var messages = [
        { "name": "Rildo", "message": "something", "date": "2015-07-01 11:12:34" },
        { "name": "Rildo", "message": "something", "date": "2015-07-01 11:14:30" }
    ],
    content = '';

$.each(messages, function (index, e) {
    var time = e.date.substr(-8,5);
    content += time + ' ' + e.name + ': ' + e.message + '<br>';
});

$("body").append(content);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```